# PrerenderIO Meteor Usage

Tags: javascript, ajax, meteor, prerender

I am attempting to use the prerenderIO Package in my meteor web app and am not sure if I am using it correctly. I followed to instructions on the package and have added the package to my webapp, then set my prerenderIO token in my settings.json file like so...

settings.json

```
{
"PrerenderIO": {
    "token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

},
"public": {

},
"private": {



}
}
```

Is there another step that I am missing? Do I need to call a method somewhere? Any insight would be hugely appreciated and thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to get prerender.io setup and tested with your Meteor app locally:

1) Install the [dfischer:prerenderio](https://atmospherejs.com/dfischer/prerenderio) package:

```
meteor add dfischer:prerenderio
```

2) Add the Prerender settings to your `settings.json` file:

```
{
  "PrerenderIO": {
    "token": "yourtoken"
  }
}
```

3) Start your app locally (making sure to reference your `settings.json`):

```
meteor --settings=settings.json
```

4) Install and start a local Prerender server for testing (make sure you change the default port of 3000 since it will conflict with Meteor's default port):

```
git clone https://github.com/prerender/prerender.git
cd prerender
npm install
export PORT=3100 
node server.js
```

5) Access your local Meteor app through your local Prerender instance:

```
http://localhost:3100/http://localhost:3000
```

6) In your browser, view source; you'll see the rendered HTML for your application instead of referenced javascript files/calls.